# Why suddenly spring asks me for aspectj?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, aspectj

I'm currently using spring security for my project.
After adding this bean (user for remember-me feature):

```
    <b:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <b:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <b:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </b:bean>
```

User token still wasn't saved. All because 'dataSource' was configured to autoCommit=false.

So first thing that I did was (really ugly because I had to create one more class, but it was working):

```
 import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

 @Transactional
 public class TransactionalJdbcTokenRepositoryImpl extends JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl {}
```

So much better solution for me was the following:

```
    <b:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <b:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <b:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </b:bean>

    <tx:advice id="tokenRepoAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config proxy-target-class="false" expose-proxy="false">
        <aop:advisor id="tokenRepoAdvisor"
                             advice-ref="tokenRepoAdvice"
                             pointcut="bean(jdbcTokenRepository)"/>
    </aop:config>
```

Pure XML no unnecessary classes:

But for some reason spring requires aspectj now!

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
... 68 more
```

Why? Without this config my dao layer was working just fine wiht @Transactional annotation. How to avoid adding aspectj library but still preserve xml config?

Answer (score 0):

After rereading spring docs, I have found a solution:

```
    <tx:advice id="tokenRepoAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
            class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="proxyInterfaces" alue="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
                <property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>tokenRepoAdvice</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

And the initial problem was a parent class of JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl (it has final methods - that's why aspectj was required)

Comment: The reason AspectJ was required was due to the use of `<aop:advisor pointcut-"" />` the pointcut is parsed with AspectJ.